# Streaming video by QtGStreamer on QML

Tags: qt, qtgstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I try to use QtGStreamer 1.0 to create a media player on qml. I use some samples n QtGStreamer example, the player application run OK but not qmlplayer application. It builds successful but can't run out. The output log show:

> QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
>
> Failed to create qtquick2videosink. Make sure it is installed correctly

I need help on running video by QtGStreamer on qml. Thanks

Comment: The first message has nothing to do with the second. And the code is just not able to find QtGStreamer in the system.

Comment: The code can find QtGStreamer library because it compiles without error. The player application (media player with QtGStreamer for QtWidget) can play video successfully

Comment: If the linkage with library is dynamic it is quite simple: either .so or .dll not found - possibility. Or maybe the other form of dynamic component used by Qt.

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
QGst::init(&argc, &argv);
```

before initializing objects helped me.